# Core Plot:animating a pie slice on touch of particular index

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am plotting a pie chart and implementing the sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex delegate.I want the slice at selected index to come out on touch.How do i achieve this?I had seen the radialOffsetForPieChart delegate which plots slices with distance between two slices but how do i call this method on touch of a particular index?

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent discussion about this on the Core Plot [discussion board](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/c08085dd63676ae5#). Basically, you call `-reloadData` on the plot and return a new offset when you want to change the slice offset. You can call it repeatedly with a timer if you want to animate the transition. There is an outstanding issue to make animating the transition easier.

Comment: This question is three years old. He already asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961957).