# How to repeatedly call a method (reload...) with a timer to animate a transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, nstimer, core-plot

I implemented `corePlot` in my `xcode` project. I'm trying to "explode" a slice of the pie chart **with** animation. Here is the method I'm using:

```
- (void)radialOffsetForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    if (myIndex == idx) {
        return 20;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have another method which calls `[pieChart reloadRadialOffset];`.

For example:

```
- (void)thisMethod {
    [pieChart reloadRadialOffset];
}
```

How can I animate the `reloadRadialOffsets`?

Comment: You can't really make a smooth animation using a timer. That must be implemented in the drawing method already. Usually you do it by creating a layer with animatable properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added an example to the "Simple Pie Chart" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app. I added two properties to the controller to hold the index of the selected slice and the desired offset value. Since the offset is a `CGFloat` it is easily animated using Core Animation or `CPTAnimation`.

Set the index to `NSNotFound` to indicate that no slice should be selected. You could also use an array or set of indices if you want to highlight more than one slice at a time.

```
self.offsetIndex = NSNotFound;
```

Trigger the animation to offset the slice:

```
self.offsetIndex = idx;

[CPTAnimation animate:self
             property:@"sliceOffset"
                 from:0.0
                   to:35.0
             duration:0.5
       animationCurve:CPTAnimationCurveCubicOut
             delegate:nil];
```

The plot datasource needs the radial offset method:

```
-(CGFloat)radialOffsetForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return index == self.offsetIndex ? self.sliceOffset : 0.0;
}
```

The `sliceOffset` property needs a custom setter to trigger the plot to update the offsets during the animation:

```
-(void)setSliceOffset:(CGFloat)newOffset
{
    if ( newOffset != sliceOffset ) {
        sliceOffset = newOffset;

        [self.graphs[0] reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your question is bit confusing. Your question title says "how to reaptedly call a mathod using timer" and at the end of your question it changes to "How can I animate the reloadRadialOffsets?".

**For repeatedly calling a method you can use any of the following options**

**option 1.**

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(animatedPie:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

**option 2:**

[self performSelector:@seletor(animatePie) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

and in your method

```
-(void) animatePie
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
    {
        [pieChart reloadRadialOffsets];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
        [self performSelector:@seletor(animatePie) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }]; 
 }
```

Here the repeated method will be called agian with a delay once the animation is complete.

When you wanted to stop the animation call

```
 - (void)cancelPerformSelector:(SEL)aSelector target:(id)target argument:(id)arg
```

When timer is used it will be fired once the interval is elapsed.

**For animation**

You can use

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
    {

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

or user

```
  CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:key];
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The reason I'm confused, is because at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreplot-discuss/wICF3WNnauU it says "You can't animate this with Core Animation, 
although you probably fake it with a timer and repeatedly reloading 
the selected index. "

Comment: @Horray I do n't know exactly you are trying to animate the pie chart. So post your code here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code. In this UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat is helpful for repeat animation what you want to achieve..

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5
                      delay:1
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:2];
                     [pieChart reloadRadialOffsets];

                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

//Still you want to call method using timer

```
    NSTimer *animateTimer;
    animateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(thisMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
   [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:animateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
   [animateTimer fire];

- (void)thisMethod {
    [pieChart reloadRadialOffsets];
}
```

Hope it helps you...!